# How do I do the equivalent of O365-Excel "Download A Copy" in c#?

Tags: excel, office365

We have a client that has an Excel spreadsheet they are maintaining in O365.   This is an embedded workbook, not a workbook sitting on one drive or something like that.

The client has given us the URL, and it seems to be set to read-only for everyone.  We do not have to provide credentials or anything to get to the spreadsheet, just bring it up in your favorite browser.

What I'm looking for is, how can we do the equivalent of "Download A Copy" to create a copy of that workbook locally.

I've looked at microsoft.sharepointonline.csom and Microsoft.SharePoint.client, neither seem to be working for what I need.

So the question is, what does it take to do a "Download A Copy" using C#, O365 and Excel?

Note: the only access we have is the URL.   Nothing else is available for us to tap into.

Thanks,
Nick